# Can I specify a string as the initial value for an HTML5 date input?

Tags: iphone, html, ipad

I want to use the HTML5 input type="date" to trigger the native date picker on a web application within the iPhone. I don't have an initial value to set the date to, so I would like to set it so that it reads "MM/DD/YYYY" on the screen initially, and upon focus, brings up the iOS native datepicker set to the current date.

Any suggestions on whether this is possible? I have tried a few ways and they don't seem to work.

Comment: You mean like you want initially the value to be the value of today in that input?

Comment: Yes, and when the user focuses on the 'MM/DD/YYYY' spot on the screen, it pulls up the native datepicker on the iphone and defaults it to today's date.

Comment: I think you need to work with JavaScript in order to do that. Native date input does not set it automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Try with placeholder atribute

```
<input type="date" name="mydate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY">
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it does not work in the iphone simulator, I'm afraid.